# Django templates problem — {% if object|length > 4 %} raises TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html

Tags: comparison, filter, django-templates

I have the following in my template.

```
{% block content %}
    {% for album in albumsList %}
        {% if fotosList %}
            <div class="photoalbum-wrapper">
                <h3>{{ album.title }}</h3>
                <ul class="photoalbum">
                    {% for foto in fotosList %}<li>item</li>{% endfor %}
                </ul>
                {% if fotosList|length > 4 %}
                    <a href="#" class="trigger">больше <span>&#9660;</span></a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}  
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And it raises TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html.

If i write simple `{{ fotoList|length }}` it works okay.

Answer (score 22):

This is a very old question. Since then, newer versions of Django support [operators in if-statement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#id2) out of the box, so the following code will work just fine:

```
{% if fotosList|length > 4 %}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `fotosList.count` instead of `fotosList|length`. you will get desired result.

Comment: This is assuming `fotosList` is a `QuerySet` or something else which implements `count()`

Answer (score 5):

FYI **if** tags with the operators ==, !=, <, >, <=, >=  are supported now in the development version of Django.

Answer (score 2):

`{% if fotosList|length > 4 %}` is not a valid tag; you can't use greater than/less than operators in the Django `if` tag. (You *can* use [operators](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators) in the latest development release, but I'm assuming you're not using the latest version from Django's SVN repository.)

The reason you get the `TemplateDoesNotExist` error is because Django is throwing a 500 Internal Server Error (due to the invalid tag), but you haven't supplied a 500.html error template, as noted [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-a-404-page-not-found-view).